# Serialize array to query string parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Currently I do some code refactoring and try replace generation of query string by concatentation to serializing of json object

From:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'./services/DataService/getDetails?metric=9&'+dashBoards.getFilter()+'groupby=quarter&'+dashBoards.options.time.start1+'&'+dashBoards.options.time.end1+'&peergroup='+dashBoards.options.peerGroup,
    type:"GET",
```

To:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'./services/DataService/getDetails',
    data: jsonObject,
    type:"GET",
```

Almost everything works fine, except one thing. If `jsonObject` contains array field it looks in query string like that:

```
...?metric[]=1&metric[]=3
```

Instead of

```
...?metric=1&metric=3
```

Is there way how can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: You have to pass data in `post` type rather then `get` and in ajax `data` you can send it like you have mentioned. Also you can do it like `data: JSON.stringify(jsonObject)` and use type `POST`.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi `JSON.stringify` is not needed, OP do not send JSON

Comment: Only change `type:"GET"` to `type:"POST"`

Comment: even query sting doesn't seem to be valid one.

Comment: Agree. `JSON.stringify` is not needed. Looks like string concatination is the best way here. I would prefer keep to use 'GET', since I just get data and don't change a state of a resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it adding to `$.ajax` parameter `traditional: true`.

[Here you can find reference why](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)